# Can't get permission's guids in microsoft graph api

Tags: powershell, permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create an application with specific GraphAPI permissions. I want to do it automatically, so powershell is my choice. The only thing that is missing are the GUIDs of the GraphAPI permissions, which are nowhere to be found in the super awesome Microsoft documentation.

What I gathered from several other questions already asked(and marked as answered lol) is this:

```
    Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
    $graph = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
    $graph.AppRoles
```

This should give me a list of all the application permissions that the GraphAPI has to offer.
Unfortunately $graph.AppRoles(neither $graph.Oauth2Permissions) does not exist in the Object that I receive. (I am aware of the difference between delegated and application permissions, and that they are found in the Oauth2Permissions/AppRoles property.)

Got any suggenstions?

Comment: Please refer to this [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/psignoret/9d73b00b377002456b24fcb808265c23) and let us know if it helps

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity That's a bit overkill. I went with Allen Wu's answer and adjusted it a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth2Permissions and AppRoles properties exist in Azure AD Powershell.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $psCred
$graphsp1 = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
$graphsp.AppRoles
$graphsp.Oauth2Permissions
```

You can also use Microsoft Graph API to get the Application/Delegated permissions.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

Just call Microsoft Graph in Powershell using `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me, though it was not quite what I was looking for. Just a small adjustment. I posted my complete answer

Comment: @Redman I'm glad to know that you have got what you want. But I still want to clarify that `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/` can only get the permissions which have been assigned to this Azure AD app. Per my understanding, if you want to create a new AAD app and assign Graph Permissions, you need to know the permission id  in advance. `servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'` can list all the Graph permissions. Then you can add Microsoft Graph permissions while creating the application in powershell. Correct me if there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Redman As you mentioned in your post "This should give me a list of all the application permissions that the GraphAPI has to offer." So my answer is to give you all the permissions Microsoft Graph offers.

Comment: Yeah, I did not communicate every aspect of my problem. That's on me. You absolutely did answer the question I asked. Though, what I really was looking for: I already had an AAD App with Graph permissions and I wanted to extract those permissions to assign the same permissions on another AAD App in another tenant

Comment: @Redman BTW, if you want to get permission id which has been assigned to an Azure AD app, just view the manifest file of the AAD app on Azure portal to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Allen Wu's answer I was able to extract the permissions GUID.

Though, it was not

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

this call that held the information, it was

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/"
```

this was one.
Then with some basic filtering I got what I needed

```
$headers = getToken
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method 'Get'
do {
    $result.value | ForEach-Object {
        if( $_.displayName -eq "YOUR_APPLICATION_DISPLAYNAME") {
            $result = $_.requiredResourceAccess | Where-Object resourceAppId -eq "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
            break
        }
    }
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $result.'@odata.nextLink' -Headers $headers -Method 'Get'
    $result = $result
}
while($result.'@odata.nextLink')
```

in $result we have this

```
resourceAppId:"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
resourceAccess:[Object[14]]
[0]:@{id=e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d; type=Scope}
[1]:@{id=660b7406-55f1-41ca-a0ed-0b035e182f3e; type=Role}
[2]:@{id=242607bd-1d2c-432c-82eb-bdb27baa23ab; type=Role}
[3]:@{id=2280dda6-0bfd-44ee-a2f4-cb867cfc4c1e; type=Role}
[4]:@{id=46890524-499a-4bb2-ad64-1476b4f3e1cf; type=Role}
[5]:@{id=98830695-27a2-44f7-8c18-0c3ebc9698f6; type=Role}
[6]:@{id=9a5d68dd-52b0-4cc2-bd40-abcf44ac3a30; type=Role}
[7]:@{id=afdb422a-4b2a-4e07-a708-8ceed48196bf; type=Role}
[8]:@{id=70dec828-f620-4914-aa83-a29117306807; type=Role}
[9]:@{id=7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61; type=Role}
[10]:@{id=5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b; type=Role}
[11]:@{id=230c1aed-a721-4c5d-9cb4-a90514e508ef; type=Role}
[12]:@{id=18a4783c-866b-4cc7-a460-3d5e5662c884; type=Role}
[13]:@{id=df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214; type=Role}
```

You can see, that according to the resourceAppId we are talking about Microsoft GraphAPI permissions. The type property indicates if it is a delegated or application permission. Scope = delegated
role = application